# How to execute a custom Eclipse Editor

Tags: configuration, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I have created a graphical editor using Eclipse-GMF. So now I can create diagram files. What I would like to do is execute the diagram files by clicking the green button.

So basically I would like to create a custom run configuration for a plugin that I have created.

I would like the custom run configuration to launch an Eclipse-RCP application that will read the runned diagram. But when i choose my RCP application in the Run as product or Run as application it opens normally for about 20secs then it crashes...

So my question is how do i configure this correctly??

Comment: Is there some stack trace that might help us?

Comment: Well here is a pastie of the error log file http://pastebin.com/gUjB2HN4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extend the org.eclipse.debug.launch* extension points to have your own launch configuration, launchers, launch tabs, etc.

Comment: So I've been able to create a run as configuration, but how do I make it call a certain method in my code? I followed this tutorial http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Launch-Framework/launch.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe these crashes that you mention are related to [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333630). The [crash log](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=186151) is identical to the one you posted in your comment. From what I can see, the issue was with Eclipse Helios on Windows 7 when Mylyn is installed on the target platform. The bug report states that it's solved in 3.7 M7. See [this comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333630#c2) on how to prevent your plugin from crashing the workbench.
 Hope that this helps :).